# Exporting ipywidgets to a website

Tags: javascript, python, html, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

I have a Python program in Jupyter Notebook that uses `interact` from the module `ipywidgets`.

```
interact(my_func, filter_by=filter_by_list, format_type=format_dict.keys())
```

I want someone to be able to open the notebook on a website somewhere and use the interactive widget without requiring Python or anything else, just like [here](https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2013/12/05/static-interactive-widgets/#SymPy-Math).

Answer (score 7):

You can check out this website: http://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/embedding.html#python-interface

```
from ipywidgets import IntSlider
from ipywidgets.embed import embed_minimal_html

slider = IntSlider(value=40)
embed_minimal_html('export.html', views=[slider], title='Widgets export')
```

According to the docs it produces an export.html file.

Comment: two years later, it's very minimal, almost unusable.